# Is it possible to group by more than 2 columns in a sharepoint List ... NOT USING SHAREPOINT DESIGNER

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

Ive searched the web and the only soloutions that appear are using Sharepoint Designer. However due to the nature of my work i cannot access the sharepoint site through sharepoint designer (silly I know). Is there another way to group by 2 columns ??